# For on-premise cluster, what is the recommended solution for load-balancing?

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy, bare-metal-server

I have a k8s cluster, and need to host a few websites, currently I am using host network way to proxy the traffic.

However, as the traffic grows, I will need a more scalable solution to load balance traffic.

I have tried some tutorials on the internet with bare metallb https://metallb.universe.tf/, but it was not successful. I am not familiar with network technologies, would someone recommend a solution for on-premise load-balancer hardware, or baremetal loadbalancer software that are easy to install and maintain?

Comment: hi and welcome. Actually metallb(e.g in spike with minikube) is what you  need. At least I would recommend you to use metallb. maybe you may want to create in parallel brand new question about issues you are facing with metallb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [keepalived](https://keepalived.org/manpage.html) with [haproxy ingress controller](https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress) for a HA Solution.

Here a example link for a possible solution [How To Set Up Highly Available HAProxy Servers with Keepalived and Floating IPs on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-haproxy-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04)